# Ajax function (Unexpected token) in AJAX Call

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

so I have been testing a bunch of new different JS code to see if I can get the POST request to send information to a SharePoint list. When I run my newest block, it tells me "Error: Line 20: Unexpected token" when I call `$.ajax` saying the period is what is unexpected? I truly don't understand.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        saveDelivDetails();
    });

});

function saveDelivDetails(){
    var itemType = GetListItemTpye(listname);
    var item = {
        "__metadata":{"type":itemType},
        "Program":$("#dProgram").val(),
        "Deliverable":$("#dDeliverable").val(),
        "To":$("#dTo").val(),
        "Date":$("#dDate").val(),
        "Approved":$("#dApproved").val(),
        "Notes":$("#dNotes").val()
    };
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listname+"')/items",
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError,

    });
    function onSuccess(data){
        alert("New Item Created");
        $("#txtSubmitName").val();
    }
    function onError(error){
        alert('error' + error);
        console.log(error);
    }

function GetListItemType(name){
    return "SP.Data."+CharacterData(0).toUpperCase().name.slice(1)+"ListItem";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `,` after line 19.

```
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listname+"')/items",
```

Comment: Thank you! I hate the small errors like this they drive me insane. Now it is telling me unexpected end of input aswell, but when I click on the console (</script></DIV>) thats what is throwing the error?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I was missing the closing } from saveDelivDetails() function